# How to WhatsApp full resolution photos from iPhone to Android

Tags: iphone, photos, android, whatsapp.app

On Android, I can choose to attach a "document" and then browse the image or video files and select the one I need. On iPhone, it seems to work the same way except that I don't seem to see the full file system of the device, and I cannot browse to the image location. Is there a way, without using a Mac?

As a side note, Telegram is happy to allow attaching a file from the Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (out of many) could be downloading the picture to your iCloud and then selecting the "Document" from Whatsapp from iCloud to send a full resolution picture.

Comment: What if I don't use iCloud? It's full since long ago. It was not my plan to pay Apple a monthly fee to use their admittedly beautiful device I paid 800 euros for.

Comment: The first 5 GBs of iCloud Drive are free. However you can use any other cloud storage solution you wish that supports the selection of "Document" via Whatsapp. Feel free to mention your preferred cloud storage service so we would have a better view of the situation we are having here.

Comment: I guess I may be lacking knowledge here. Can I just send a photo from my smartphone? Why do I need to upload it to the cloud first, in order to send it from my smartphone? Or do I misunderstand something? Generally, I have a Google One subscription, would that work? (I still prefer not to use it for this purpose if I can.)

Comment: I think you're understanding the situation right. It's not Apple nor is it Telegram being superior. It's Meta and the of that Whatsapp enjoying their monopoly role in quick messaging so they don't need to add fancy stuff like that into the application. You can download the pictures from your Google Photos to your Google Drive and then select from the "Documents" the Google Drive folder and paste the full resolution picture to the chat.